# How can I view (offline) the full English Wikipedia on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, software

I want to download the complete English Wikipedia (not just the 45,000 article version floating around) for viewing offline  on my Mac.

I have downloaded Okawix, and downloaded a torrent with Wikipedia (en.wikipedia.okawix, available on the okawix site) to view within Okawix.  However, I can't figure out how to view this downloaded torrent within Okawix, so I'm not sure what I can do.

What is the best way to do this? Is there software to download and view Wikipedia?

Comment: You would be better off buying the [Encylopedia Britannica](http://store.britannica.com/) it comes as several CD's and the advantage is that you can use it as a reference, as Wikipedia is not considered to be a reputable source of information, as it can be edited by anyone.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: It might be, because an offline mac client, would do the job..

Comment: Are you looking for help using Okawix to actually read the dump it provides or would you be open to using the [wiki provided dumps of data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) and setting up your own wiki to serve up the content using http?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how you want to use the data once it's on your mac.

To narrow this down a bit, you can refer to the page that wikipedia has made to guide people like you that want to get a local copy of content and actually use it.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Pay particular attention to the sections:

- [Help importing dumps into MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Help_importing_dumps_into_MySQL)
- [Static HTML tree dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Static_HTML_tree_dumps_for_mirroring_or_CD_distribution)
- [Dynamic HTML generation from a local XML database dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#Dynamic_HTML_generation_from_a_local_XML_database_dump)

The first option has you loading the dumps into your own database and is the most powerful, but means you will be running your own web server / database - your own little copy of wikipedia on your mac. The second two are guides to simply opening the dumped files in a web browser or other program that can render HTML and follow the links to files that rest on your mac's file system.